# WCF Client Performance

Tags: wcf

I used WCF to call a Java based web service and constantly get 1.4 second or 1.5 second response time. I used exactly same SOAP request in SoapUI to call the same web service and constantly get 0.9 second to 1 second response time.

Both requests are initiated from my local computer, both requets hit same target.

It is very hard for me to believe it will take 0.5 second to serialize and deserialize, but other than this what else can impact the performance?

**Update 1 - included sample code**

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        //Trust all certificates, non-production uses self-signed certificate
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        MyServiceClient.MyService.Spml2ServicePortTypeClient client = new MyServiceClient.MyService.Spml2ServicePortTypeClient();

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MyServiceClient.MyService.SuggestUserIDRequestType webRequest = new MyServiceClient.MyService.SuggestUserIDRequestType();
            webRequest.requestID = "MyId";
            webRequest.givenName = "Hardy";
            webRequest.sn = "Wang";
            webRequest.uid = "some value";

            sw.Start();
            MyServiceClient.MyService.SuggestUserIDResponseType response = client.suggestUserID(webRequest);
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Reset();

        }
```

Comment: How, precicely, are you capturing your metrics?

Comment: Use Fiddler to determine if this is network time or not.

Also did you use the exact soap or maybe wcf created a more verbose one?

Possibly wcf uses http proxy and soapui is not configured to it.

Also does this happen only on the first call after you create the wcf proxy or also on the second call on the same proxy? the first time wcf may compile a serialization assembly.

Comment: @EtherDragon, it is very precise. I used Stopwatch to capture each call's time.

Comment: @YaronNaveh, I will do another try after return to office on Monday.

Comment: @hardywang Sorry, ambuguious word used. I meant, what steps do you take to measure the time for each type of call to the web service. Depending on how your test is configured, you might be seeing time variations of the UI to update, not for the data to be transmitted...

Comment: @EtherDragon, I have updated the original post to include my sample code how the measurement was taken.

Comment: Thanks @hardywang. You might try having the service log it's performance results. If you find consistent performance results on the service code-behind, but the 0.5 second difference in the WCF call, then it's likely due to (de)serialization.